# Apply Jackson coercion configuration feature to specified deserialization cases

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-modules

There are some fields, which should be deserialized from `String` to `Double`. However, the general `ObjectMapper` configuration doesn't allow coercion of scalars:
`configure(MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS, false)`

Before Jackson [coercion configuration feature](https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/jackson-2-12-most-wanted-4-5-cbc91c00bcd2) implementation, this `String` -> `Double` conversion was done with a custom deserializer. For example:

```
data class SeriesFrameInputChannel(
    @JsonDeserialize(using = TestDeserializer::class)
    @JsonProperty("test_field")
    val testFieldForConvertion: Double
)

class TestDeserializer : StdDeserializer<Double>(Double::class.java) {
    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): Double {
        return _parseDoublePrimitive(p, ctxt)
    }
}
```

However, after the coercion config was introduced, the following error occurred:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot coerce String value ("2.2") to `double` value (but might if coercion using `CoercionConfig` was enabled)
```

The issue could be solved by adding the following lines to the `ObjectMapper` configuration:

```
coercionConfigFor(LogicalType.Integer)
   .setCoercion(CoercionInputShape.String, CoercionAction.TryConvert)
```

However, it will affect the deserialization behavior of other fields, not only `testFieldForConvertion`.

What is the appropriate way to apply Jackson coercion configuration to the specified field case(-s), in order to avoid the deserialization behavior changes for other fields?